# How to unit test a rule in a grammar

Tags: unit-testing, antlr

I have a grammar with a rule such as:

```
item_list returns [EnumSet<Item> value]
    : item { $value = EnumSet.of($item.value); }
    | item_list ',' item { $value = $item_list.value; $value.add($item.value); }
```

This is just one rule within the grammar: an `item_list` on its own is not a valid expression. But I would like to unit test the individual rules as well as the whole grammar. I have tried a method that looks something like:

```
@Test
void testItemList() {
    assertThat(parse("dog,car").item_list().value).containsOnly(Item.DOG, Item.CAR);
}
```

Unfortunately the parser fails on this text because it is looking for EOF before it recognises the rule to use. I can artificially add a new rule:

```
item_list_test returns [EnumSet<Item> value]
    : item_list EOF { $value = $item_list.value; }
```

Which then allows the test to pass (using `.item_list_test()`).

This is obviously kludgy and requires adding useless rules purely for the purpose of testing. Is there a way to force the parser to parse a rule as though it was terminated?

Comment: I think that you should add a rule above it. Something like `program : item_list | EOF`.

Comment: @Phil1970 I might not have made it clear but item_list is just one rule within the grammar - the question is really how to test a rule rather than the whole grammar

Comment: **Well, it is quite normal when doing test to have to setup a test environment that might do some preparation steps.** You can probably write a function to reduce the amount of code to write in each test. Maybe something like `parseAsProgram("item_list", "dog,cat")`.

Comment: @Phil1970 It's normal to have setup code in the test (such as my `parse` method) but in this case I've got to put a test rule in the grammar itself. That seems less normal. And to unit test every rule I'd need an additional test rule for every actual rule which makes the grammar harder to read. I'm suspecting there's a way to set up Antlr to force the rule to terminate - just not sure what it is.